# Need help extracting data from a file

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I'm a newbie at python.

So my file has lines that look like this:

> -1 1:-0.294118 2:0.487437 3:0.180328 4:-0.292929 5:-1 6:0.00149028 7:-0.53117 8:-0.0333333

I need help coming up with the correct python code to extract every float preceded by a colon and followed by a space (ex: `[-0.294118, 0.487437,etc...]`)

I've tried `dataList = re.findall(':(.\*) ', str(line))` and `dataList = re.split(':(.\*) ', str(line))` but these come up with the whole line. I've been researching this problem for a while now so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
:(-?\d\.\d+)\s
```

In your code that will be

```
p = re.compile(':(-?\d\.\d+)\s')
m = p.match(str(line))
dataList = m.groups()
```

This is more specific on what you want.

In your case .* will match everything it can

Test on Regexr.com:

[image]

In this case last element wasn't captured because it doesnt have space to follow, if this is a problem just remove the \s from the regex

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I was messing around on regexr.com but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
import re
line = "-1 1:-0.294118 2:0.487437 3:0.180328 4:-0.292929 5:-1 6:0.00149028 7:-0.53117 8:-0.0333333"
for match in re.finditer(r"(-?\d\.\d+)", line, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
    print  match.group(1)
```

Or:

```
match = re.search(r"(-?\d\.\d+)", line, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    datalist = match.group(1)
else:
    datalist = ""
```

---

Output:

```
-0.294118
0.487437
0.180328
-0.292929
0.00149028
-0.53117
-0.0333333
```

---

Live Python Example:

http://ideone.com/DpiOBq

---

Regex Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/nR4wK9/3

---

Regex Explanation

```
(-?\d\.\d+)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(-?\d\.\d+)»
   Match the character “-” literally «-?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> s='-1 1:-0.294118 2:0.487437 3:0.180328 4:-0.292929 5:-1 6:0.00149028 7:-0.53117 8:-0.0333.333'
```

With your particular data example, you can just grab the parts that would be part of a float with a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r':([\d.-]+)', s)
['-0.294118', '0.487437', '0.180328', '-0.292929', '-1', '0.00149028', '-0.53117', '-0.0333.333']
```

You can also split and partition, which would be substantially faster:

```
>>> [e.partition(':')[2] for e in s.split() if ':' in e]
['-0.294118', '0.487437', '0.180328', '-0.292929', '-1', '0.00149028', '-0.53117', '-0.0333.333']
```

Then you can convert those to a float using `try/except` and `map` and `filter`:

```
>>> def conv(s):
...     try:
...         return float(s)
...     except ValueError:
...         return None 
... 
>>> filter(None, map(conv, [e.partition(':')[2] for e in s.split() if ':' in e]))
[-0.294118, 0.487437, 0.180328, -0.292929, -1.0, 0.00149028, -0.53117, -0.0333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple oneliner using list comprehension -

```
str =  "-1 1:-0.294118 2:0.487437 3:0.180328 4:-0.292929 5:-1 6:0.00149028 7:-0.53117 8:-0.0333333"
[float(s.split()[0]) for s in str.split(':')]
```

Note: this is simplest to understand (and pobably fastest) as we are not doing any regex evaluation. But this would only work for the particular case above. (eg. if you've to get the second number - in the above not so correctly formatted string would need more work than a single one-liner above).